# How to change default row height in fullcalendar day view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

How to change default height of row elements in FullCalendar day view(agenda)? Need CSS class or Javascript function. Refer to screenshot for details-
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please post some code, a jsfiddler would be great. thanks

Answer (score 9):

If you want to change the height of each 30-minute block, you should use the following CSS and adjust the height as you need. The default value is 2.5em.

```
.fc-time-grid .fc-slats td {
    height: 2.5em;
}
```

Take a look at [**a working jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/c8rcnqmb/).

Comment: This works. But simply changing the CSS misaligns up the `nowIndicator`. Any idea how to scale the indicator correctly while resizing the rows?

Comment: I cannot see any misalignment of the indicator line when using `height: 2.5em;`. I's at the quarter at :15 and in the half at :30

Comment: @Fanky this answer goes back to 2015 and a lot has changed on Fullcalendar, so this might not be completely accurate with the newest version. Thanks

Comment: Well I tested this solution and it seems it works fine with 4.1.0. Know any better?